# Is there an even faster approach than swap-and-pop for erasing from std::vector?

Tags: c++, stdvector, c++20

I am asking this as the other relevant questions on SO seem to be either for older versions of the C++ standard, do not mention any form of parallelization, or are focused on keeping the ordering/indexing the same as elements are removed.

I have a vector of potentially hundreds of thousands or millions of elements (which are fairly light structures, around ~20 bytes assuming they're compacted down).

Due to other restrictions, it *must* be a `std::vector` and other containers would not work (like `std::forward_list`), or be even less optimal in other uses.

I recently swapped from simple `it = std::erase(it)` approach to using pop-and-swap using something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myVec.size();) {
  // Do calculations to determine if element must be removed
  // ...

  // Remove if needed
  if(elementMustBeRemoved) {
    myVec[i] = myVec.back();
    myVec.pop_back();
  } else {
    i++;
  }
}
```

This works, and was a significant improvement. It cut the runtime of the method down to ~61% of what it was previously. But I would like to improve this further.

Does C++ have a method to remove many non-consecutive elements from a `std::vector` efficiently? Like passing a vector of indices to `erase()` and have C++ do some magic under the hood to minimize movement of data?

If so, I could have threads individually gather indices that must be removed in parallel, and then combine them and pass them to erase().

Comment: You can make your own. If you know the number of elements in advance you can make a few improvements, like using a single resize() instead of several pop_back().

Comment: Depending on several factors, like the density of erased elements and the cost of checking, you might have a better result making a thread-safe swap-and-pop using an atomic, instead of looping another time to erase the elements.

Comment: *"Like passing a vector of indices to `erase()`"* -- all the options for what can be passed to `vector::erase` are listed in [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase). If `vector` lacks a member function to do what you want, then there is no "magic under the hood" that could not be done in your own function. (I think the answer is that you should write your own function, but I easily could have overlooked something.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [std::remove_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) algorithm. You  could use it like this:

```
auto firstToErase = std::remove_if(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(),
                                   [](const & T x){
                                   // Do calculations to determine if element must be removed
                                   // ...
                                   return elementMustBeRemoved;});
myVec.erase(firstToErase, myVec.end());
```

cppreference says that following code is a possible implementation for remove_if:

```
template<class ForwardIt, class UnaryPredicate>
ForwardIt remove_if(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, UnaryPredicate p)
{
   first = std::find_if(first, last, p);
   if (first != last)
       for(ForwardIt i = first; ++i != last; )
           if (!p(*i))
               *first++ = std::move(*i);
   return first;
}
```

Instead of swapping with the last element it continuously moves through a container building up a range of elements which should be erased, until this range is at the very end of vector. This looks like a more cache-friendly solution and you might notice some performance improvement on a very big vector.

If you want to experiment with a parallel version, there is a version (4) which allows to specify execution policy.

Comment: It looks like remove_if on its own was about the same or slightly worse performance in my case (~3% worse). However, adding std::execution::par_unseq was a massive improvement, cutting it down to about a 5th of its original execution time. Thanks!

Comment: To add, note that actually `remove_if` does not do swaps, hence if you have something like `unique_ptr` elements, the pointed destructors will be called right away. If there is a need to do more passes on the marked for removal elements, a `std::partition` or `std::stable_partition` should be the choice. They can be combined with erase afterwards anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Or, since C++20 you can type sligthly less and use [erase_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2).
However, in such case you lose the option to choose execution policy.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an even faster approach than swap-and-pop for erasing from std::vector?

Ever since C++11, the optimal removal of single element from vector without preserving order has been move-and-pop rather than swap-and-pop.

> Does C++ have a method to remove many non-consecutive elements from a std::vector efficiently?

The remove-erase (std::erase in C++20) idiom is the most efficient that the standard provides. `std::remove_if` does preserve order, and if you don't care about that, then a more efficient algorithm may be possible. But standard library does not come with unstable remove out of the box. The algorithm goes as follows:

- Find first element to be removed (a)
- Find last element to not be removed (b)
- Move b to a.
- Repeat between a and b until iterators meet.

There is a proposal [P0048](https://github.com/WG21-SG14/SG14/blob/master/Docs/Proposals/unstable_remove.html) to add such algorithm to the standard library, and there is a demo implementation in https://github.com/WG21-SG14/SG14/blob/6c5edd5c34e1adf42e69b25ddc57c17d99224bb4/SG14/algorithm_ext.h#L84

Comment: The proposal was rejected for want of more impressive performance improvements.